# Approximation of Integral for T = 1K

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation

Suppose we have the following integral: $$\int_{0}^{x_{\text{max}}}\frac{x}{1+e^x}dx,$$
where $x\equiv \frac{\Delta E}{k_BT}$. We are supposed to argue that it is justified to consider $x_{\text{max}}\rightarrow \infty$ for $T\approx 1 \ \text{K}$.

Please note that we are supposed to do this in Physics, so I don't think we need a strict proof. My idea was so far was to substitute x and put in $T \approx 1\ \text{K}$, but I obtain this integral: $$\int_{0}^{E_{max}}\frac{\Delta E}{k_B^2}\frac{1}{1+\exp\{\frac{\Delta E}{k_B}\}}d\left(\Delta E\right),$$ but then the question remains why I can take $E_{max}\to \infty$?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Are you supposed to integrate wrt to $\Delta E$ or wrt to $T$ ? By the way, the first integral has a simple closed form.

Answer (score 1):

We write $g(x)=\tfrac{x}{e^x+1}$.
The approximation you are talking about is valid as  long as $x_{max}\gg1$.
Since the integral converges in the limit of $x_{max}\rightarrow \infty$ we can then write

$$
I=\int_0^{\infty}dxg(x)-\int_{x_{max}}^{\infty}dxg(x)\sim C-\int_{x_{max}}^{\infty}dx(xe^{-x}+O(xe^{-2x}))
$$

where $C$ is some constant.
So 
$$
I\sim C-(x_{max}+1)e^{-x_{max}}+O(x^2_{max}e^{-2x_{max}})
$$
which means that all terms expect of the first are asymtotically negligble

and we have

$$
I\sim C+O(x_{max}e^{-x_{max}})
$$

note again that the above asymptotic simplifications are only valid if our above asssumption holds true (so that we can Taylor expand the second integral).